# Hadoop single-node starting issue

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to bring up the hadoop standalone server (in aws) by executing 
`start-dfs.sh` file but got the below error

```
Starting namenodes on [ip-xxx-xx-xxx-xx]
ip-xxx-xx-xxx-xx: Permission denied (publickey).
Starting datanodes
localhost: Permission denied (publickey).
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/tools/GetConf : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:808)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:442)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:64)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:430)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:323)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Installed Java version is **javac 1.7.0_181** 
Hadoop is 3.0.3.

Below is the path contents in profile file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
#export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR

export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/scala
export PATH=$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin
```

What is the issue ? is there anything i'm missing?

thanks

Comment: Hadoop 3 dropped support for Java 7, I believe. But why aren't you just using EMR?

Answer (score 1):

ssh-keygen

2.It will ask for folder location where it will copy the keys, I entered /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa

3.it will ask for pass phrase, keep it empty for simplicity.

4. `cat /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa.pub .>> ssh/authorized_keys` (To copy the newly generated public key to auth file in your users home/.ssh directory)

`ssh localhost` should not ask for a password

start-dfs.sh (Now it should work!)

Comment: i did as told, but now i'm getting a different error as  - mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied, any suggestions.

Comment: have you tried creating the directory? or HADOOP_LOG_DIR to a directory you have access to?